# How to return RequestHeaders as a ResponseBody using a filter in Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I am implementing a Spring Cloud Gateway. But, I need a filter which can extract all the RequestHeaders from a http call (via postman) and after that it will get back a ResponseBody with the extracted RequestHeaders.

There is no need to call the downstream services afterwards. Following is my **application.yml** file:

```
server:
  port: 8082

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: todo-access-manager
          uri: http://localhost:9125
          predicates:
            - Path=/todo-manager/**
          filters:
            - CustomAuthPreFilter
```

**CustomAuthPreFilter:**

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthPreFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<CustomAuthPreFilter.Config> {
    public CustomAuthPreFilter() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            ServerHttpRequest.Builder builder = exchange.getRequest().mutate();

            // Getting all request headers
            var requestHeaders = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders();

            // Need to send back all requestHeaders as a responseBody without going to downstream services.
            // ToDo

            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(builder.build()).build());
        };
    }

    public static class Config {
        //Put the configuration properties for your filter here
    }
}
```

**RequestHeaders:**

[image]

**Problem:** My CustomAuthPreFilter is calling successfully when I run the code. I am also getting the requestHeaders. But, after that how can I return back the requestHeaders as a responseBody?